# How to save Button with onSaveInstanceState?

Tags: android

Here is a short version of my code:

I need to save Button view for orientation change and I am trying to use putParcelable().

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    }

    @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    
            outState.putParcelable("button", (Parcelable) button);
        }
```

But I always get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
```

And could you give an advice on best practices? Is it okay to store Views with onSaveInstanceState or not?

Comment: Usually you don't store views in `onSaveInstanceState`. Instead you save state, any kind of data, such as Strings, Ints, etc. that you want to restore later and show in a view. Why do you want to 'save' a view? Or what are you trying to do?

Comment: @fernandospr I got ArrayList with buttons that I shuffle every onClick. What about app, it's just one more "Guess what it is" app with 4 buttons for selection.